# useEffect() and localStorage Showing Both Options For Value

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, use-effect

I have two tabs on a website. When a user clicks a tab, it becomes active `('aria-selected', true)`. When the user clicks the other tab, THAT tab becomes active, and the other one becomes inactive. I want the user's choice to persist on page load (whether initially loading or on refresh). The below code shows BOTH tabs as `"active"` when the page loads - what could I be doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```js
 //Select the relevant tab when the page loads:
  useEffect(() => {
    const tabs = document.querySelectorAll('[role="tab"]');
    const localStorageView = localStorage.getItem('view');
    if (localStorageView === 'default') {
      alert(localStorageView);
      tabs[0].setAttribute('aria-selected', false);
      tabs[1].setAttribute('aria-selected', true);
    } else if (localStorageView === 'myView') {
      alert(localStorageView);
      tabs[0].setAttribute('aria-selected', false);
      tabs[1].setAttribute('aria-selected', true);
    }
  });
```

Comment: do you have a code sandbox I can look up or even a git repo